# jQuery select one element from same class

Tags: jquery, hover, element

I have a problem with jquery. How to select an element which I only hovered?

I guess it is related to `$(this)` , but the problem is that I do not know how to implement it in this case.

Here is my jquery code.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.nav_link').hover(function(){
        $('.nav_line').animate({
          width: '100px'
        }, 1000);
      }, function(){
        $('.nav_line').animate({
          width: '0px'
        }, 500);  
      });
    });
  </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
      <nav role="navigation" class="nav">
        <div class="nav_line"></div>
        <a class="nav_link" href="#">PASLAUGOS</a> 
        <a class="nav_link" href="#">KONTAKTAI</a>
      </nav>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you post a fiddle example please?

Comment: Actually my code does not work on jsfiddle, but works on localhost. ^^

Comment: Please post your fiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.nav_link').hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.nav_line').animate({
          width: '100px'
        }, 1000);
      }, function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.nav_line').animate({
          width: '0px'
        }, 500);  
      });
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/PjswL/

Comment: Look to my dknaack post comment. Thanks

Comment: @JuliusJ, Please post your comment.

Comment: There are nav_link and nav_line.

Comment: @JuliusJ, Please post your html part in your question.

Comment: May is it better to do with pure CSS3?

Comment: @JuliusJ, I have updated my answer. Also demo provided in my answer. Please check.

Comment: But why the text does not dissapear? :O Besides, Is it possible to prevent from many pushy hovers?

Comment: @JuliusJ, Go through animate function in jquery documentation.

Comment: So may it would be better to make it with pure CSS3?

Answer (score 0):

Just use an instance of `this` in your selector:

```
$('.nav_link').hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".nav_line").animate({
      width: '100px'
    }, 1000);
  }, function(){
    $(this).siblings(".nav_line").animate({
      width: '0px'
    }, 500);  
});
```

Comment: @JuliusJ -- Made an edit, try again - Your HTML was a bit hard to read due to formatting

Comment: Here comes two bads. One of them is a line appears only over first element and the other is you could hover many times asyou want and a line will repeat those times. :(